# Use excel pivot table layout to add label to entry

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am currently trying to add a new label to an entry in a table based on which area the entry falls into when placed into a pivot table. There are a total of 7 categories that arise when they are place in the table.

What I am looking at is for when the "site" falls into a categories of the "stage" that it is part of. Picture below.

[image]

Is it possible to update the main table with labels relating to the categories found in a pivot table?

So in the table it would look like...

```
A6NGN9-288   MCI

A6NHG4-39    Control+MCI+AD

O00300-152   AD
```

Comment: Why would you want to lose the granularity of your results?  According to your picture, you now want 3 rows for A6NHG4-59 to each have the same ambiguous label.  Unless you want those three rows summed so you only have 1 row for the Multi-Label.  Which would still beg, why would you want to lose the granularity of your results?

Comment: But to answer your question: Yes. It is possible to update the main table with labels relating to the categories found in a pivot table.  But you would have to let us know how your underlying data is grabbed.  Is it originally in a SQL table?  Or a CSV file you read into Excel? Or is it just on a sheet where someone manually entered the data?  Answering how your data is stored and called into your pivot table will allow people to help you with your question.  Because the are different answers based on which method you are using.

Comment: I figure out how to do it with R and Access. Long and all over the place but it works.